# How do I use a variable to represent 10 column names in plt.title

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 10 columns from col1 to col10 and I put them into a variable col. I would like to draw an individual bar graph for each column, so there would be 10 bar graphs generated.

My question is how to represent these 10 column names in plt.title?

For example, the total of 10 titles should be INS % by col1, INS % by col2, INS % by col3, ..., INS % by col10.

Thank you so much!

```
col = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9','col10']

for col in num_columns:

     totals = df.groupby(col)['INS'].count() 
     pos_counts = df.groupby(col)['INS'].sum()


     pos_pcts = pos_counts / totals
     neg_pcts = 1 - pos_pcts


     plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
     plt.barh(pos_pcts.index, pos_pcts.values, label='likelihood of buying INS')
     plt.barh(neg_pcts.index, neg_pcts.values, label='likelihood of not buying INS',
     left=pos_pcts) # neg_pcts bars have their leftmost point where the pos_pcts end
     plt.title(f'INS % by col')
     plt.legend()
     plt.show()
```

Comment: Should your `num_columns` be list instead defined as `col`?

Comment: @student Hi! Thank you for your reply!  I just tried to write 'num_columns' in plt.title and the 10 titles became INS % by num_columns in each bar graph. So I'm wondering is there a special representation to replace the names of those 10 columns.

Comment: Can you try using :  `plt.title('{}'.format(col))` instead of `plt.title(f'INS % by col')`? assuming `num_columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9','col10']`

Comment: @student It works! I really appreciate your time and help!!! Thanks a lot!!!